# Nginx reverse proxy doesn't work properly

Tags: vue.js, nginx, proxy, cors, nginx-reverse-proxy

I wrote a page and it can be visited in [sheyh.cn/multi/#/singleText](https://sheyh.cn/multi/#/singleText).
I tried to make a request to `https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/`, It works properly in Vue devserver proxy and the config is like this

```
 devServer: {
    port: "8082",
    proxy: {
      "/oauth": {
        target: "https://aip.baidubce.com",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
      },
    },
  },
```

After I upload the file to server the CORS error occured.

Then I tried to config my Nginx proxy like this.

```
#PROXY-START/multi

location /oauth/
{
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods 'POST,PUT,GET,DELETE';
    proxy_pass https://aip.baidubce.com/;
    proxy_set_header Host aip.baidubce.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    # proxy_hide_header Upgrade;

    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    #Set Nginx Cache

    set $static_filefFIlksdb 0;
    if ( $uri ~* "\.(gif|png|jpg|css|js|woff|woff2)$" )
    {
        set $static_filefFIlksdb 1;
        expires 1m;
    }
    if ( $static_filefFIlksdb = 0 )
    {
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
}
#PROXY-END/
```

The error is still there
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/2.0/token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=DiChTG01AUDydg4gUfb88f03&client_secret=zdU2g9ZLAG9w2owWgwPEaGfGUrWHmB8j' from origin 'https://sheyh.cn' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I've added Access-Control-Allow-Origin in my config, but it doesn't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a Access-Control-Allow-Origin error. The reason for this error is that you have accessed the domain name `https://aip.baidubce.com` under the domain name `https://sheyh.cn`. You can check the code, it should be called directly `https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/2.0/token` This interface.

It is recommended that you call `https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/2.0/token` to use jsonp.

chinese:

这是一个跨域错误，产生这个错误的原因是因为你在 `https://sheyh.cn` 这个域名下访问了 `https://aip.baidubce.com` 这个域名。你可以检查一下代码，应该是直接调用了`https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/2.0/token` 这个接口。

建议你调用 `https://aip.baidubce.com/oauth/2.0/token` 这个接口使用 `jsonp`.